# How to get more info while installing an application?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Suppose I want to install an application named **aeiou**. If I go to software center and look for the application, it gives information about the application and also shows some of the optional plugins that I can install. Is there a way we can access these using commandline? There seems to be no information regarding this on man page of `apt-get`.

Comment: Yes. Your answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
apt show <package_name>
```

to get the information regarding a package, including packages that this package depends on and also its description.

For example, do

```
apt show geany
```

to get information regarding geany

For more information, refer to [the manual page of apt](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt).

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know there is something called apt.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using `apt-cache show <package>` for 7 years or so, but here might be more sophisticated methods out there ever since, for example, you could try `aptitude`.